# Too large frame error when running spark shell on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I am having troubles starting spark shell against my local running spark standalone cluster. Any ideas?
I'm running this on spark 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Starting the shell or regular app works fine in local mode, but both fail with below command.

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://localhost:8080
...
20/04/05 00:34:47 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to localhost:8080: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593
20/04/05 00:34:47 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master localhost:8080
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:303)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593
        at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the incorrect port was being used.

This line appeared in the standalone master log:

```
20/04/05 18:20:25 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://localhost:7077
```

Port 8080 is for the master UI.
The correct command was:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077
```