# Unable to connect to Spark cluster via SQL Workbench

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are new to Apache Spark & have setup a standalone Apache spark cluster v3.1.2. In our cluster we have a master node & two worker nodes. Out of two worker nodes, one node has 4 cores & 4GB of memory & the other node has 4 cores & 48GB of memory. From our spark cluster we are able to execute queries that will connect to S3, Redshift & fetch the required data set. But when we are trying to connect to the apache spark cluster from SQL workbench we are getting below error.

SQL workbench error

```
21/09/08 10:01:11 DEBUG TransportServer: New connection accepted for remote address /X.X.X.X: 2715.
21/09/08 10:01:11 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /X.X.X.X: 2715 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 34440615463
        at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/09/08 10:01:11 INFO Master: X.X.X.X: 2715 got disassociated, removing it.
```

We tried to search for the solution over community & as per some suggestions mentioned in the community posts we have updated the following configuration

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 3001)
spark.conf.set("spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem", "200M")
spark.conf.set("spark.reducer.maxReqSizeShuffleToMem", "200M")
spark.conf.set("spark.network.timeout value", 150)
```

But with the above configurations also issue is not yet fixed. Can anyone please suggest how should we resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you check the port? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051316/too-large-frame-error-when-running-spark-shell-on-standalone-cluster

Comment: Yes I have checked the port. Spark master is running on port 57077 & from SQL workbench I am trying to connect to the same port.