# Hive failing to create spark session

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I tried a lot and read a lot of docs of spark and hive. Things dont even match up. For example
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started
in this docs of hive, hive says that 2.3.x is tested for spark 2.0.0
but in spark docs ( https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/building-spark.html ) it says that spark 3.3.2 is built for hive 2.3.9
Information of docs mismatch and also when I try with hive 2.3.9 on spark 3.3.2, I am getting errors when hive is trying to create spark session.

This error shows up when i do like

```
select count(*) from table_name;
```

### Error

Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
Failed: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to create spark client.

So i checked the logs of hive and here are some information that you may need. FYI, my spark runs on port 4040 in localhost.

WARN TransportChannelHandler : Exception in connection from localhost/127.0.0.1:4040
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593
ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from localhost/127.0.0.1:4040 is closed
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
ERROR [f0fd81a8-0d73-43d0-814e-bda0253c132a main] client.SparkClientImpl: Error while waiting for client to connect.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancel client 'cc1f8b8a-0bfd-4574-9b6d-90bb0238a71e'. Error: Child process exited before connecting back with error log Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout

To see full error log -> https://pastebin.com/CiuHRCsy

Comment: Not 100%  a duplicate, but I would guess that you try to connect to a wrong port:  [Too large frame error when running spark shell on standalone cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051316/too-large-frame-error-when-running-spark-shell-on-standalone-cluster)

Comment: @werner i have put the reason for that error, check it :))     And yes your comment actually gave me the tip to reach this solution as if port is correct, maybe the IP address that spark or hive is looking for might be the issue which lead me to read upon the configs of spark i mentioned in hive-site.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for that error. In hive-site.xml which is in **$HIVE_HOME/conf**, I changed the value of configuration **spark.submit.deployMode** from **cluster** to **client** which solved the issue as I am running spark and hive locally.